# HTTP response was too large: 10485810. The limit is: 10485760

Tags: http, brainfuck

i have written an online brainfuck interpreter ..!! the problem is when i take the text input , it gives an error !!... 
HTTP response was too large: 10485810. The limit is: 10485760.

it seems the max limit of gae is 1mb.. how can i get around it !1

Comment: Have you tried using http compression? (Btw, 10485760 is 10MB, not 1MB.)

Comment: no what is http compression ?

Comment: seems like you're crazy :) BTW. how did you create the interpreter? Is it BF too? If not what kind of language/web server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Look again. The limit is 10 MiB.

This is not a limitation in the HTTP protocol, so the limitation is in the server platform that you are using (which you haven't specified in your question).

That's more data that you would reasonably send to the browser, so you clearly have an eternal loop that sends data until the buffer is full.

You can get around the limit by turning off buffering, but that will not remove the problem. Instead your code will just loop until the browser crashes from the huge response.

Answer (score 1):

Optimise your Interpreter.
Whatever BF input you had, you really should not exceed the 10 MB response limit.